# Foundational proof for Mersenne primes

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

I know how to prove that, if $2^n-1$ is prime and $n>1$, then $n$ is prime.

But how do we prove that, if $a^n-1$ is prime and $n>1$, then $a$ must equal 2?

Comment: If you thought about the proof of the result you know how to prove, that might give you a clue!

Comment: Corollary of [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1154592/if-an-1-is-prime-then-a-2-and-n-is-prime?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If we say $P(a)=a^n-1$ we have that $P(1)=0$ and by [Polynomial remainder theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial_remainder_theorem) we get that
$$a-1\mid a^n-1$$

Comment: Well, I know your main idea of proving the result asked above. But, what is $P(1)$?

Comment: @Idonknow $P(a)=a^n-1$ a polynomial