# How do Ι show if $a^n-1$ is prime for $n >1$ then $a=2$?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

It is well known that $a^n-1$ is prime Mersann formula  for some pimes $p$ , I would like to show this implication if $a^n-1$ is prime for $n >1$   with $a$ is a positive integer then $a=2$ ?

**Edit**: I edited the question as it is related to the precedent question

**Note** : I have tried to show that for $a$ is odd it's obvious no integer $a$ satisfy $(a^n-1)$ which means it's not prime for an odd integer $a$

Comment: Note that $a-1\mid a^n-1$.

Comment: $3^1-1$ is prime.

Comment: I know , in my question i assume that if a^n-1 is prime number than a =2

Comment: But $3^1 - 1$ is a counterexample to "if $a^n-1$ is prime then $a = 2$" unless you put additional restrictions on $n$.

Comment: thanks for that i forget to add exeception for n=1 , now it's fixed

Comment: Duplicate: [If $a^n-1$
is prime then $a=2$
and $n$
is prime?](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1154592/201168)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Hint**
$$a^n-1=(a-1)(a^{n-1}+...+a+1)$$

So, **as long as $n>1$**,you get two terms.

Answer (score 1):

Hint let  $a\neq 2$ then we can do $a^n-1^n=(a-1)(a^{n-1}+....+)$ now if $a\neq 2$ then the subtraction a-1 becomes even as 2 is largest even prime which gives odd sum when 1 is subtracted and all other primes give  even numbers. Tgus $a=2$